how to correctly show current data with laravel pagination?
I'm having trouble with pagination in Laravel 10. I have generated 13 data from my database and I'm on page 1, so I'm expecting to see something like

"Showing 1 to 8 of 13 results"

but instead, my code is displaying the message

"Showing 1 to 13 of 13 results"

what am I doing wrong? any help is appreciated.
this is my code:
    public function index(Request $request)
    {
        $client = new \GuzzleHttp\Client();

        $perPage = $request->query('per_page') ? : 8;
        $page = $request->query('page') ? : 1;

        $url = "http://localhost/api/culinary?page=$page&per_page=$perPage";

        $response = $client->request('GET', $url);

        $json = json_decode((string)$response->getBody(), true);

        $paginatedResult = new LengthAwarePaginator(
            $json, // the data to be paginated
            count($json), // total count of the data
            $perPage, // number of data shown per page
            $page, // current page number
        );

        $view_data = [
            'title' => 'Browse Culinary',
            'data' => $paginatedResult,
        ];
        return view('culinary.index', $view_data);
    }

and I'm using this code in the index.blade.php to show the pagination part
{{ $data->withQueryString()->withPath('/culinary')->links() }}


if your $data has 13 items and you count that same data as the total, of course you will get only one page

You should slice the items you pass to the paginator. From the docs:

When manually creating a paginator instance, you should manually "slice" the array of results you pass to the paginator.

So, pass this to your paginator:
$offset = ($page - 1) * $perPage;

$paginatedResult = new LengthAwarePaginator(
    array_slice($json, $offset, $perPage), // paginated data
    count($json), // total count of the data
    $perPage, // number of data shown per page
    $page, // current page number
);

